# Find specific job in resque queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

In my application, I'm using Resque to resize images. If an image is in the resizing queue, I want to show a "resizing image" icon.

This means that I need to be able to find all current jobs relating to a specific model ID in the queue. Right now I do it like this:

```
Resque.peek(:resize, 0, 100).find_all { |job| /#{model.id}/.match(job["args"][0]) }
```

This is stupid. But is there any way to query the Resque queue to find all jobs where the **first argument** is equal to **[id]**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you can capture the job_id when the job is enqueued, then check the job status by looking up the job with that id.  You'd have to store the ID somewhere for re-use, obviously.

Comment: Actually, you may need another gem to do that. Just experimenting now.

Comment: This might interest you https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status

Comment: @Ronze Why do you consider the `Resque.peek(:resize, 0, 100).find_all...` example stupid?

Comment: Instead of `Resque.peek(:resize, 0, 100)` you should use `Resque.queues[:resize]`.

Comment: Some requests on the Resque issue tracker ask for Job ID's: https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/6, https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/7, and  https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/15. Read those for various workarounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of querying resque queue, you should store image meta-data along with your model.

Lets assume you are storing product images. You are likely using a Redis hash to store product details. Just add another flag like this -

`hset product:123 is_resizing true`

You can them perform a simple lookup to show the resizing image icon. At the end of your resque job, delete the `is_resizing` key, and add the `resized_image_url` key.

Comment: Thanks for that. My app structure makes it hard to do this though, as I'm not storing any of these images in the DB. It's a requirement of my app. But I probably need some sort of table that tells me what is currently resizing. It just seems like that exact data is in the Resque que.

Answer (score 10):

Give [resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) a try. It is an extension to Resque that adds job tracking.

> resque-status provides a set of simple classes that extend resque’s default functionality (with 0% monkey patching) to give apps a way to track specific job instances and their status. It achieves this by giving job instances UUID’s and allowing the job instances to report their status from within their iterations.

Note: [d11wtq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322122/d11wtq) mentioned this above as a comment, but is actually the best **answer** so far.

Comment: resque-status is genius, invaluable. Especially when you want to track the completion % of a long-running job.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way might be to use a redis set to cache this information.

When you add an image to the 'resize' queue, also add the image id to the 'resize_in_progress' set using SADD. (I assume you have some kind of unique key or name to refer to the image, even if not stored in the db. Maybe the full path to the filename.)

In the 'resize' process, as one of the final actions after successfully resizing the image, remove it from the set using the SREM command.

When you want a list of all images, you can fetch that with SMEMBERS. If you want just the members for a specific model id, you might need to store a separate set for each model, named something like 'resize_in_progress_3451' where 3451 is the id of the model that has the images being resized.

See http://redis.io/commands#set for more set commands.